# Emma Report using Ant

Tags: maven, ant, emma

Our project has several modules and I am generating 'coverage.ec' for each module using emma plug-in for maven. Now I am trying to generate consolidated  coverage report for all the modules by using all *.ec files with the following ant target

```
<project name="coverage" default="emma.reports" basedir="." >

<property name="emma-reports" location="${basedir}/emma/emma-reports"/> 
 <!-- directory that contains emma.jar and emma_ant.jar: -->
 <property name="emma.dir" value="${basedir}/emma/lib" />
 <property name="emma.coverage" location="${basedir}/target" /> <!-- this dir has all the *.ec files-->

 <path id="emma.lib" >
<pathelement location="${emma.dir}/emma.jar" />
<pathelement location="${emma.dir}/emma_ant.jar" />
</path>
<taskdef resource="emma_ant.properties" classpathref="emma.lib" />
   <target name="reports">
         <emma enabled="${emma.enabled}" verbosity="verbose" >
            <report >
                <infileset dir="${emma.coverage}" includes="*.em" />
                <txt outfile="${emma-reports}/coverage.txt"/>
                <html outfile="${emma-reports}/coverage.html"/>
            </report>
        </emma>
   </target>        

</project>
```

Target runs with no errors, but no report gets generated? I am missing something here? Is there any other approach to consolidate reports?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I generate Emma code coverage reports using Ant?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52984/how-do-i-generate-emma-code-coverage-reports-using-ant)